# How to Archive specific row to a new list?

Tags: list, delete, archive

Im newbie in sharepoint, so I would like to ask you for help. I need to delete items with specific conditions and then archive them to a new list. All this because of reduce number of items in original list which is over 2000. Do you have any ideas?

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Workflows check you conditions and exclude the item;

Use powershell to run the workflow every day.